# Using Multer and Express to upload and display files

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I'm using [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) to upload images with express and node from a form, however all the files names come out like "8f92a1388f70c6c88eb32489f6bcfcc9". There isn't even an extension attached. How to I display this on the client side?

Comment: Did you find the solution to this issue?

Answer (score 4):

**try:**

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, '/where/ever/the/upload/dir/is')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.orignalname)
  }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage })
```

**Instead of:**

```
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })
```

**Requesting the file:**
With the proper permissions set on the file/or directory your server should be able to request it fine, remember to explicitly write the file name with an extension if you aren't doing anything fancy after the file is written ;)

> If you want more control over your uploads, you'll want to use the
>   storage option instead of dest. Multer ships with storage engines
>   DiskStorage and MemoryStorage; More engines are available from third
>   parties.
>    **--The Horse**
>   (**ref:** [github: expressjs/multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer))

**Note:** Multer will not append any file extension for you, your function should return a filename complete with an file extension

Comment: Then what does replace upload.single('field')?

Comment: NOTE: There is a typo in the given property name - `file.orignalname` should be `file.originalname`

Comment: @armadadrive agreed.. the edit queue is full so my change can't go in